# Attach a Fragment to the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to attach a Fragment to my MainActivity programmatically by using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}
```

it gives me an error: `cannot resolve add method`

The application can be found [here](https://github.com/MoaadGit/Weather)

Comment: whats the id of your container put that in add function

Comment: your activity_main id is your Frame id ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

By this:

```
Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager.begintransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your take framelayout in activity_main.after that

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framelayout_id,fragment);

than its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like that

```
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
    }
```

and call this in your onCreate Method

```
 openFragment(new yourFragment());
```

In your beginTransaction().replace method you have to pass the view from which you want to replace your fragment with