# How can i call fragment to activity?

Tags: java, android

I created a progress dialog into a fragment by using [this effect](https://androidexample365.com/a-beautiful-ripple-animation-for-your-app/). Now i must call it in different activities. When I call the effect the buttons at the background must not work. How can I do that?

First i need to learn how to call the fragment in a different activity. Then i must make the buttons at the background unclickable but there are many of them so ‘setclickabla(false)’ would be a tiring choice.

**Progress Dialog Fragment XML:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ProgressDialogFragment">

<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    android:id="@+id/ProgressDialogs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CB000000"
    app:rb_color="#80FFFFFF"
    app:rb_duration="2500"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_scale="6">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

**ProgressDialogFragment.java**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_dialog, container, false);
    RippleBackground rippleBackground = (RippleBackground)view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressDialogs);
    rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: So the question is how to disable item from clicking or something else? Could you explain the needed behavior? *"shouldn’t must work"* sounds a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it could work like that, but you probably want to look for something like that in documentation for this library. Or you could just try to use `setClickable(false)` if it's possible.
But if under *"must not work"* you mean that they shouldn't appear - I don't know how to help you.

Comment: First i need to learn how to call the fragment in a different activity. Then i must make the buttons at the background unclickable but there are many of them so ‘setclickable(false)’ would be a tiring choice.

Comment: If you need to call fragments you just need to use `SupportFragmentManager` and replace the container to fragment. If you search for that you will find something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081536/attach-a-fragment-to-the-activity) or with .xml code included.

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons at the background to respond to clicks, you have to implement the onClick listener of the various buttons.

```
<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
android:id="@+id/ProgressDialogs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CB000000"
app:rb_color="#80FFFFFF"
app:rb_duration="2500"
app:rb_radius="32dp"
app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
app:rb_scale="6">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/centerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

In your layout above, you are making use of ImageView which I changed to centerButton and you can make it respond to clicks this way:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_dialog, container, false);
    RippleBackground rippleBackground = (RippleBackground)view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressDialogs);
    rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();

Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.centerButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // your respond to clicks
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Call your fragment from your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Fragment fragment = new MainFragment(); // your fragment
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I couldn’t explain myself. I want to call this fragment into an activity. The buttons that belong to this activity must be unclickable.

Comment: Yes. You can call fragments from activities. Here is how:

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    }

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.